# accessed another scope field but it won't change parent value until reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I had searched and found a solution like below
but eventhougth parent controller shows me the right value .But page won't change the value.I tried $scope.apply(); but still nothing changed

```js
angular.extend(this, $controller('parentCtrl', {$scope: $scope}));
$scope.childValue = $scope.parentValue;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your child controller under parent controller you can access by using "    $scope.$parent "

```js
$scope.childValue =$scope.$parent.parentValue;
```